# How can I rearrange an object key to the beginning of a grouped object

Tags: javascript, object

My question is in the code comments:

```js
var myObj = [
  {
    0: 'company1',
    1: { count: 3 }
  },
  {
    0: 'company2',
    1: { count: 3 }
  },
  {
    0: 'company3',
    1: { count: 2 }
  },
  {
    0: 'company1',
    1: { count: 1 }
  },
];

var companytoshift = 'company2';
var f = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
  f.push(myObj[i][1].count);
}

var isMultipleSameValues = samevaluemultiplecompany(f);

if (isMultipleSameValues) { //we have multiple company with same value
  /*
   if 'companytoshift' exist in the object array
     if 'companytoshift' has a count value that is same with other companies
       then shift that company to the top of the same count value group.
        
        For the example object above, after we perform the function, it would be this:
        
        var obj = [
        {
          0: 'company2',
          1: {
            count: 3
          }
        },
        {
          0: 'company1',
          1: {
            count: 3
          }
        },
        {
          0: 'company3',
          1: {
            count: 2
          }
        },
        {
          0: 'company1',
          1: {
            count: 1
          }
        },
      ];
  */

  /* as you can see company2 moved above company1 because it had the same count value as another company, which is 3, and also because it was the company in the `companytoshift` variable
   */
}

function samevaluemultiplecompany(a) {
  var counts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
    if (counts[a[i]] === undefined) {
      counts[a[i]] = 1;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

([*fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/2t56s0gy/))

Comment: is this question about sorting? if so, you could just sort the array by `count`. if not, what is it about? maybe it is easier to understand, if you include `myObj` as formatted JSON, instead of a console copy.

Comment: Hi Nina... No not sorting. So `companytoshift` is the company to shift. It could be any company. If `companytoshift` is in the object and it has same value as other companies, I want to make `companytoshift` as the first entry for the same value set. does that make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by `has same value as other companies`? Company name and count above are different.

Comment: do you want to mutate the array or to sort with the wanted company to top and it's same caount companions?

Comment: `company1` and `company2` has count value 3

Comment: what about the order of other items?

Comment: Doesn't matter... everything else can remain the same. I am interested in the `companytoshift`

Comment: so from my example above `company1` should be after `company2` since they both have same count and `company2` is the value for `companytoshift`, make sense?

Comment: I will rephrase my question so you can understand better... one min please

Comment: i understand the part of searching for a company and the ones with the same count. both, or more are going to top. the rest, unsorted follows. do you want to take a new array or use the old one, sorted?

Comment: I would like to modify the existing one. I think once i rephrase my question it will be understood better.

Comment: Ok question has been updated. let me know if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the count of the given `company` and sort by `company` first and then by the count. By having a stable sort, the other elements are unsorted at the end of the array.

```js
function sort(array, company) {
    var count = array.find(([c]) => c === company)[1].count;

    return array.some((c => ({ 1: { count: v } }) => v === count && ++c === 2)(0))
        ? array.sort((a, b) =>
            (b[0] === company) - (a[0] === company) ||
            (b[1].count === count) - (a[1].count === count)
        )
        : array;
}

var array = [
        ["company1", { count: 3 }],
        ["company3", { count: 1 }],
        ["company2", { count: 3 }],
        ["company4", { count: 0 }],
        ["company5", { count: 0 }]
    ];

console.log(sort(array, "company2"));
console.log(sort(array, "company3"));
console.log(sort(array, "company5"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Looks like that may work... Let my test it out. Thank you. i know it was confusing :/

Comment: One issue... if company1 has count 12 and I add a new company2 to the array, let's say value 3, the function puts the new company first and it shouldn't. The sort/shift should ONLY occur if the company in `""` is in the array with same value as other companies in the array, otherwise it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: then check this in advance with counting the same `count`.

Comment: You beat me to it... I was doing it also. Thanks for the example though... someone else might find it handy... I am going to do some more testing now. :)

Comment: Quick question, is there another way to do it without the use of the arrow (`=>`) function?